# Swipe control similar to Control Center's Brightness/Volume sliders

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a sliding control similar to Apple' brightness or volume sliders in iOS's Control Center (pictured below).

I was thinking of using `UISlider`, but the problem is that on a `UISlider`, you need to click on thumb to slide it. On this control you can press anywhere on it and slide up or down even if you go outside of it.

What control or gesture would be best to use to create that functionality in Swift?

[image: A screenshot of the brightness and volume sliders in iOS's Control Center]

Comment: Stack Overflow is not designed for judgment calls like what "would be best". And a question like "how do I code this interface?" is too broad. Try to focus on a specific programming issue that you are having with your actual code.

Comment: You can use touches Began / Moved / Ended (start here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621142-touchesbegan) ... You could also use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` (start here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer)

Comment: I'd recommend a pan gesture recognizer. It's should be pretty easy to detect a touch-and-slide gesture using that.